# Para que serve o método split no ionic?

Tags: array, ionic, ionic3, ionic2, split

Bem, estou desenvolvendo uma app com o ionic 3, e ouço falar de um método chamado split, mas eu nunca entendi sua funcionalidade. Apenas entendi que está relacionado a arrays. Diante disso :

- O que é o método split?
- Como é a sua usabilidade?

Answer (score 0):

> O método split() divide um objeto String em um array de strings ao
>   separar a string em substrings.

O split não é uma função exclusiva do ionic, é uma função do javascript, mas está presente em várias linguagens com algumas variações. Ela pertence ao objeto `String` e sempre vai retornar um array de strings contendo os valores separados pelo delimitador, igual o `explode` do php. Exemplo

```js
console.log("Batatinha quando nasce".split(' '))
```

O resultado esperado é um array com cada palavra separado por espaços.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split